# Need to rebuild docker image after syntax error in Node application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am running a NodeJS app in a docker container, and I am using `docker compose watch` so I can hot-reload when I make code changes.

This works fine until there's a syntax error, which causes the NodeJS image to terminate.  When I correct the syntax error and try to restart the NodeJS image, the image dies again, and the logs show the same original syntax error.

The only way to fix this anomaly is to run `docker compose --build` (which works fine, image restarts).  I then shutdown the container and run `docker compose watch` again.

As a workaround for now I am using nodemon to watch for code changes.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Here is my compose.yaml file

```
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: develop
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync+restart
          path: ./
          target: /usr/src/app/
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
```

EDIT:

Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction.   In compose.yaml I tried a bind mount together with the new watch config, but looks like their respective target paths can't overlap,

When running docker compose watch I get the errors:

Htar: can't remove old file usr/src/app/node-app-1.js: Permission denied
WARN[0011] Error handling changed files for service server: 1 error occurred:

See this answer to a question from the audience at the DockerCon 2023: https://youtu.be/u1q8AyNMxd4?t=2133

For now I'm not using docker compose watch, I am instead use npm run start/dev in my Dockerfile and compose.yml, which serves my purposes.

Comment: It could be an incorrectly configured command or entrypoint in the docker-compose.yml file. What are these configurations?

Comment: Thanks Borislav, posted compose.yaml file

Comment: it doesn't seem like you mount any volumes. are you developing directly in the container? can you post the Dockerfile too please?

Comment: @Hoopra If volumes are used docker will not monitor these directories.
ukmasa check my answer, it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that should work as expected. After fixing the syntax error, the server will restart, and you will get an updated application.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:21
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./
          target: /app
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
        - action: rebuild
          path: package.json
```

Start the application

```
docker-compose watch
```

Please note that if a syntax error occurs and you use sync+restart, the container will not start again automatically. In such cases, you will need to manually stop and then start the container.

Currently, the rebuild command is used for any changes made in the /app directory.

You can check a sample project here https://github.com/bgizdov/nodejs-docker-compose-watch-quickstart-template

#### Alternative solutions:

- Use `node --watch`
  https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--watch

```
--watch
Starts Node.js in watch mode. When in watch mode, changes in the 
watched files cause the Node.js process to restart. By default, watch 
mode will watch the entry point and any required or imported module. 
Use --watch-path to specify what paths to watch.

This flag cannot be combined with --check, --eval, --interactive, or the REPL.

node --watch index.js
```

- Use `nodemon`
  https://github.com/remy/nodemon

```
nodemon is a tool that helps develop Node.js based applications by 
automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the 
directory are detected.

nodemon does not require any additional changes to your code or method of 
development. nodemon is a replacement wrapper for node. To use nodemon, 
replace the word node on the command line when executing your script.
```

Node --watch and Nodemon work faster because you don't have to wait for the container to rebuild and they use volumes that are always in sync.

Here is a sample for them as well: https://github.com/bgizdov/nodejs-nodemon-watch-docker-compose-quickstart-template

Comment: Thanks Borislav, but it doesn't look like I can use a bind mount with the same target directory that's being watched by  docker compose watch.

Comment: @ukmasa, I believe that nodemon and node --watch are better solutions, as they are much faster and provide instant updates. It seems that you are already using now node run dev, which may potentially call node --watch.

Here is an example that incorporates both: https://github.com/bgizdov/nodejs-nodemon-watch-docker-compose-quickstart-template.